# CSV file appearing in tabular form in iOS 11

Tags: ios, csv, ios11

I am a newbie in iOS. My application has option to download data from database into Excel or CSV format. The Excel option is working fine but when I select the "Download in CSV Format" option, it is downloading the data and displaying it in a tabular format, much similar to excel.
I checked in the browser of the device and there also the CSV file is shown in tabular format.
I would like to know, is this a feature in iOS 11, to display CSV in table format, rather than the normal single-line form in older versions?